# Ado.net ExecuteScalar() returning null

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am executing a stored procedure in c# (through vs2008) using ado.net with an ExecuteScalar command. The stored proc returns the pkey of the new record entered, but ExecuteScalar is returning null. I look in the database and a record has indeed been added. I could use an output parameter to get the value, but then I won't know why this didn't work.

When I execute the sp in ssms, the pkey is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the C# code:

```
  public int SaveNewPerson(EPerson ePerson)
    {
        int newPersonPkey;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnn.PersonData);
        using (cn)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "People.dbo.AddNewPerson"; 
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = ePerson.LastName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = ePerson.FirstName;
                cn.Open();
                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
                newPersonPkey = int.Parse(result.ToString());
                cn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // call error method
                throw new Exception(e.Message + " save new Person error ");
            }
        }
        return newPersonPkey;
    }
```

And this is the sp:

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewPerson]
            @FirstName varchar(50)
           ,@LastName varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [People].[dbo].[Persons]
           (
            [FirstName]
           ,[LastName]
            )
     VALUES
           (
            @FirstName 
           ,@LastName 
           ) 
declare @persons_PKey int 
set @persons_PKey = @@IDENTITY 
return @persons_PKey

end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ExecuteScalar` method returns the first field of the first record of the result, but as your query doesn't produce a result, it will return null.

You can either select the value instead of returning it from the stored procedure, or add a parameter with the direction set to `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` to catch what the stored procedure returns.

Comment: Of course! I thought this had worked before. Changed return @persons_PKey to select @persons_PKey and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the Stored Procedure to use a `Select Statement` to return the identity instead of using a return like this:

```
SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
```

Thus changing your procedure to:

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewPerson]
            @FirstName varchar(50)
           ,@LastName varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [People].[dbo].[Persons]
           (
            [FirstName]
           ,[LastName]
            )
     VALUES
           (
            @FirstName 
           ,@LastName 
           ) 
SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
end
```

From the documentation of the [ExecuteScalar() on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) it says that it will return the first column of the first row in the result set or null otherwise if the result set is empty.